# Fail to link UnitTest++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, gcc, cmake

I want to use [UnitTest++](https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp) in my project but I get an error on compiling:

```
CMakeFiles/BNN.dir/main.cpp.o:-1: In function `main':
BNN/main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `UnitTest::RunAllTests()'
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched the web for an answer and tried several things that's what I have right now:

```
project(BNN)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

file(GLOB SRC "*.cpp" "src/*.h" "src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB DATA_FILE "*.md")

find_package(UnitTest++ REQUIRED)
include_directories(${UnitTest++_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${UnitTest++_LIBRARY})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC} ${DATA_FILE})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})
```

I build the library by following the official guide:

```
cd path/to/unittest-cpp/builds
cmake -G "<Choose a valid generator>" ../
cmake --build ./
sudo cmake --build ./ --target install
```

My OS is ArchLinux.

What do I have to do so I can compile it with cmake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it by changing my cmake file to:

```
project(BNN)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

include_directories(src)

file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp" "src/*.h" "src/*.cpp" "tests/*.cpp")
file(GLOB DATA_FILE "*.md")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${DATA_FILE})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../unittest-cpp/builds/libUnitTest++.a)
```